# Faster way to copy slot B back to slot A after update

Tags: updates, ota-update, ab-partition

After update into Slot into B, is there any way to mirror the contents of B back to slot A? So that both slots have the same versions.

How do copy complete updated slot B back to slot A efficiently?

Comment: Search android rsync as a possible solution ?

Comment: https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/twrp-keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to do this while installing Lineage OS on my Moto X4. You can find the "copy partitions" ZIP file on the official installation site [here](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/payton/install):

> #### Pre-install instructions
>
> In some cases slot `b` can be unpopulated or contain much older firmware than slot `a`, leading to various issues including a potential hard-brick. We can ensure none of that will happen by copying the contents of slot `a` to slot `b`. This step is NOT optional.
>
> To do this, sideload the `copy-partitions-20210323_1922.zip` package by doing the following:
>
> 1. Download the `copy-partitions-20210323_1922.zip` file from here.
> 2. Sideload the `copy-partitions-20210323_1922.zip` package:
>
>    - On the device, select “Advanced”, “ADB Sideload”, then swipe to begin sideload
>    - On the host machine, sideload the package using: `adb sideload copy-partitions-20210323_1922.zip`

Comment: Any clue how does copy-partitions-20210323_1922.zip works, like what it contains what special thing it contains it copies slot A to slot B ?